# The meaning of the bold part in the text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Trump insisted h.i s inaugural crowd was the biggest in history, even
>   in the fa e of clear photographic evidence that it wasn't; his
>   then-spokesman Sean Spicer reinterpreted "crowd size" to really mean
>   "audience around the globe"; when that did not help, Trump's
>   counsellor Kellyanne Conway coined the now infamous phrase
>   "alternative facts". T his was widely mocked as implying that, when
>   reality renders your lies "fake news", you can simply move to an
>   "alternative reality" where your assertions are true. Since then,
>   members of the "reality-based community" -- to use a phrase that originated from the Bush administration -- have been treated to a spectacular series of claims, retractions aml denials, most recently culminating in **Rudy Giuliani's pithy, if utterly confused, pronouncement** that "truth isn't truth".

"pithy" seems to have a positive meaning; it means a thoughtful statement. But then what is the meaning of "if utterly confused"?

Comment: pithy doesn't mean "thoughtful". It means "short, but expressive".  Confused has its usual dictionary meaning.

Comment: @JamesK So what is the meaning of all that: the statement is short but confused?

Comment: Yes. It is short, but so confused that it is meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pithy means 'terse and vigorously expressive'

Confused is used normally.

The *if* in 'pithy, if utterly confused, pronouncement' emphasises the antithesis: loosely reworded, 'expressive, and yet idiotic, pronouncement'